# HTTP Error 400 Bad Request telegram bot api

Tags: php, httprequest, telegram, telegram-bot

i am sending a request to telegram bot with this url

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY-BOT-TOKEN>/answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id=2916104559490270755&results=[{%22type%22:%22article%22,%22id%22:%22678958501\/0%22,%22title%22:%22Violet%20Evergarden%22,%22thumb_url%22:%22https:\/\/anime-list6.cf\/public\/storage\/anime\/image\/2019\/5\/1556712020-74a0c6e3.jpg%22,%22input_message_content%22:{%22message_text%22:%22Salam%22}}]
```

but it returns an error :

```
"Bad Request: can't parse json encoded inline query results: Closing '\"' not found"
```

i don't know what that error means and i cant fix it

Comment: Please provide the whole PHP snippet.. If you are not correctly enclosing the URL, it is logical that you will get such an error..

Answer (score 0):

I'm with same problem and was resolved follow documentation, writing this is line code:

```php
    void sendYouMessage(String arguments) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://api.telegram.org/bot{YourToken}/sendMessage?chat_id={YourId}&text=${yourText}');

    var response = await http.get(url);
  }
```

I wait to can helpened!

Answer (score -1):

You can to attempt:

```
    void sendYouMessage(String arguments) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://api.telegram.org/bot{YourToken}/sendMessage?chat_id={YourId}&text=${yourText}');

    var response = await http.get(url);
  }
```

Thank you by -1!

Comment: Is this PHP or JS? as the OP asked for PHP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34378985)